# JavaScript function is not returning any boolean value or ticket calculation is wrong

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to complete an online assignment for javascript and HTML. Question is:

1. Book Ticket page – This will contain details that will be entered by the user to book train tickets
2. Thank you page – Thank you page appears after user successfully booking a ticket

The no of tickets should be greater the no of children (Use java script for doing this validation). Provide an error message in the alert box as “No of tickets should be greater than the no of children”.

·         Show date and time should be either current date or future date. (Use java script for doing this validation). Provide an error message in the alert box as “Show date and time should be either current date or future date”.

·          All the fields are mandatory (Should be done using HTML5).

·          Ticket Fare should be calculated based on the below logic. (Use Java script for doing the calculation).

o   Ticket Fare =  Fare for 1 ticket * # of tickets

o   Assume fare for 1 ticket is 200.

·         For children the fare of 1 ticket is 100.

·         Once the user submit the form,ticket fare should be calculated and displayed in the alert box as “Your approximate ticket amount is  INR“.

**The JavaScript method for calculating ticket price should return a Boolean value.**

Example: No of tickets: 4 No of children's:1 then the ticket fare will be 700.

The following error is occurring:

> Have provided all the inputs correctly, but the ticket calculation is
>   wrong or The JavaScript method is not returning any boolean value

Even though I returned values from methods and it's calculating the expected output i.e. No of tickets: 4 No of children's:1 then the ticket fare will be 700.

```js
function validations(){
    var noTickets=document.getElementById("tickets").value;
    var noChildrens=parseInt(document.getElementById("childrens").value);
    var value=document.getElementById("showdate").value;
    if(noTickets < noChildrens)
    {

        alert("No of tickets should be greater than the no of children");
        return false;

    }
    if(new Date() > new Date(value))
       {
            alert("Show date and time should be either current date or future date");
           return false;
       }
    else{
    var adults=noTickets-noChildrens;
    var ticketfare=(adults*200) + (noChildrens*100);
    alert("Your approximate ticket amount is "+ticketfare+" INR");
    return true;
    }

}
```

```css
.left{
            display: inline-block;
            width:140px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        .right {
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            display:inline;
            margin-left: 100px;
        }
        header{
        width:100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .item {
          position: relative;
          overflow: hidden;
          width: 200px;
        }
        .item img {
          max-width: 100%;

          -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
          -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
          transition: all 0.3s;
        }
        .item:hover img {
          -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
          -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
          transform: scale(1.2);
        }
```

```html
<html>
<body bgcolor="aqua">
    <header><h1>Movie Ticket Booking</h1></header>

<form action="thankyou.html" method="post" onsubmit="return validations()" autocomplete>

    <label for="name" class="left">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+[ ][a-zA-Z]+" class="right" placeholder="Enter the Name" required /><br>

    <label for="moviename" class="left">Movie Name</label>
    <input list="movies" name="moviename" autocomplete="on" class="right" required="required">
    <datalist id="movies">
    <option value="Irada"></option>
    <option value="Rangoon"></option>
    <option value="Logan"></option>
    <option value="Fist Fight"></option>
    </datalist><br>

    <label for="circle" class="left">Circle</label>
    <input list="circles" name="circle" autocomplete="on" class="right" required="required">
    <datalist id="circles">
    <option value="Silver"></option>
    <option value="Gold"></option>
    <option value="Platinum"></option>
    </datalist><br>

    <label for="phone" class="left">Phone no</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Enter Mobile # here" maxlength="10" pattern="[0-9]{10}" class="right" required ><br>

    <label for="showdate" class="left">Show date and time</label>
    <input type="datetime-local" name="showdate" class="right" required="required" id="showdate"><br>

    <label for="tickets" class="left">No of tickets</label>
    <input type="number" name="tickets" min="1" max="10" class="right" required="required" id="tickets"><br>

    <label for="childrens" class="left">No of children's</label>
    <input type="number" name="childrens" min="1" max="5" class="right" required="required" id="childrens"><br>

    <input type="submit"  name="Book My Show" value="Book My Show" class="left" style="text-align: center">

    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" class="right">
</form>
<footer>
<div class="item">
<img src="contactus.jpg" id="contactus" alt="image not found">
</div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know how can I solve this error. Any help/suggestion will be really appreciated.

Comment: Ok, so when you submit the form, it will show the ticket price in a popup dialog box, then redirect you to `thankyou.html`. What's the expected behavior? Seems like it works for me.

Comment: Yes it works for me too. That's all it had to do. But still I'm facing this error. There is this one more thing though--> In the question the ouput is written in italic style like (<i>Your approximate ticket amount is <Calculated ticket amount here> INR</i>). Well oviously <i></i> are not mentioned. But I'm wondering if they want the content in alert box in italic.

Comment: Wait so why post this question in the first place if it already works? lol. And that question is for you to decide, we can't help you with the details of your assignment

Comment: @Termhn I posted it here because I don't know if it's becuase of that or I'm making some mistakes especially in "Javascript method not returning a boolean".

Comment: Why are you using `parseInt` on a date string? Don't just copy/paste what people tell you to without applying thought.

Comment: We need more details about exactly what the assignment asks you to do in order to help you with that. Can you add the full text of what it wants you to do to your question?

Comment: I changed the 'parseInt' for date and added the full question.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about it. I have reduced the example to just the necessary bits in order to save space here.

Now the problem is that you—unless you prevent the default action of the event—the form will submit before your event listener is executed. So, you need to prevent the default action, validate the form, *then* submit the result if it passes validation.

This example goes most of the way, now you just need to send the validated response to the server. Keep in mind that client-side validation should not replace server-side validation. Nothing that faces the client should ever be trusted as it can easily be modified from the console.

There are many ways to serialize a form, then get sending the request to the server is fairly trivial (again, there are a few ways to do this).

```js
const form = document.getElementById('booking-form');

form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    const tickets  = +form.tickets.value;
    const children = +form.children.value;
    const date     = form.date.value;
    const adults   = tickets - children;
    const fare     = (adults*200) + (children*100);
    
    try {
        if(adults < 0) {
            throw "Number of children should not exceed number of tickets."
        }

        if(Date.now() > Date.parse(date)) {
            throw "Cannot book showings in the past.";
        }
    } catch(error) {
        alert(error);
        return false;
    }
    
    alert(`Your approximate ticket amount is ${fare} INR`);
    return true;
});
```

```html
<form id="booking-form" action="thankyou.html" method="post" autocomplete>
    <label>Show date and time
        <input type="datetime-local" name="date" required id="showdate">
    </label><br>
    <label>Number of tickets:
        <input type="number" name="tickets" min="1" max="10" required id="tickets">
    </label><br>
    <label>Number of children:
        <input type="number" name="children" min="1" max="5" required id="childrens">
    </label><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Book My Show">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Comment: I need to implement it with table. I cannot use form. Will it be same even with the table instead of form ?

Comment: You could do the same thing with a form _and_ a table. You _could_ use just a table then build a form using JavaScript, but why can you not have a form?

Comment: It's the requirement of the assignment that I'm completing online.

Answer (score -1):

You get a string back from `getElementById().value` so you need to convert that to a number. For example, `var not = parseInt(document.getElementById("tickets").value)`.

Also, try to use more descriptive variable name. `not` could be `numTickets` and `noc` could be `numChildrensTickets`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried parseInt to convert string to number. There is no diffrence with that. Yeah I was kinda in a hurry to complete it, so such names.

Comment: "so you need to convert that to a number" — Why? I can't see any point where the values are used in a context where they wouldn't be implicitly converted to a number (i.e. with `<` and `*` operators and the like).

Comment: `parseInt(document.getElementById("tickets").value)` — Don't use `parseInt` without a radix especially if you can't control the incoming value (as in this case where it is user input)

Comment: You're right, thought there was originally somewhere that they were doing `string + otherString` which would result in concatenation instead of implicit conversion but can't find it on rereading